# About the conditions of l'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I am reading “Calculus” (University of Tokyo Press) written by Prof. Takeshi Saito.

In this book, the conditions of l'Hôpital's rule are written as follows.

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be differentiable functions defined on some open interval $(u, a)$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ on $(u, a)$.
>   Furthermore, let $g'(x) > 0$ on $(u, a)$ or $g'(x) < 0$ on $(u, a)$.
>   Let the left limit $\lim_{x \to a-0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ converge and its value be c.

Why did he write “$g'(x) > 0$ on $(u, a)$ or $g'(x) < 0$ on $(u, a)$”?
I think it is enough to write $g'(x) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Due to [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), if $g^\prime$ changes sign, there is a point $x$ where $g^\prime(x) = 0$. It follows that the condition $g^\prime(x)\not = 0$ on $(u, a)$ is equivalent to the book's condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Gribouillis.